# What is the relation between eigenstate thermalisation and infinite heating in Floquet systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, non-equilibrium, floquet-theory

Closed quantum systems with periodically changing parameters (Floquet systems) typically heat up to an infinite temperature at large times. I have read multiple times (the last time was [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08056)) that this infinite heating is 'an incarnation of the [eigenstate thermalisation hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenstate_thermalization_hypothesis)'.

As I understand it, the Eigenstate Thermalisation Hypothesis (ETH) says that local observables computed from the many-body Hamiltonian eigenstates of the system depend continuously on the energy of the eigenstate (corresponding eigenvalue).

How can the two concepts be related? In Floquet systems, there is no energy conservation, the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian are periodic functions of time. I can imagine using the Floquet quasi-energies instead of the time-dependent eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian, but I still don't get the relation to the ETH.

Comment: There is definitely some relation, but I'm not sure it is quite the one you are suggesting. I assume the passage in that paper you are referring to is:
"In this unique ergodic phase, all Floquet eigenstates must individually yield T = ∞ correlations and exhibit volume law enanglement with the maximum thermodynamic entropy. This requirement is an incarnation of the eigenstate thermalisation hypothesis (ETH)"
I understand this as saying only that the ETH guarantees that the infinite-temperature thermal state have volume law entanglement, not that it says anything about Floquet evolution itself

Comment: @Rococo I agree 100%. Although I think ETH implies BOTH volume law entanglement AND infinite temperature correlations, not just the entanglement.

Comment: @Rococo Yes, you found the right passage. I left my question a bit vague on purpose. I know (from multiple papers) that there is a relation between ETH and the infinite temperature state of Floquet systems. I am asking for someone to clarify this relation.

Comment: @StevenMathey got it. I will extend this into an answer attempt if I get the chance.